# How to cache method's in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to `cache[redis]` javascript object which contains some
method's in it. I want to somehow cache this method's so that I can use them later independently.

## Have done so far :

`.set()` :

While saving data to cache I use Deeploop and check if any value is a function if so that convert it to the string.

`.get()` :

loop over data fetched from cache and JSON.parse it first than Deeploop over it and check if value is function syntax or not if so then use

```
new Function(`return ${value}`)
```

## Problem

if I call a cached method which is anonymous function it will be going to return a cached function which is value in `.get()` and `.set()` I will going to receive `value[realmethodname]` is not defined.

## What I want?

The best optimal way to handle methods just like handling data in when it comes to the cache.

#### `.get()` Method

```
get = async () => {
      // error handling.
      try {
        // local variable.
        let _getDetails, _datapipe

        // variable assignment.
        _getDetails = await getAsync(_id)

        // only pase and loop if _getDetails
        // is not empty else return empty data.
        if (!_.isEmpty(_getDetails) && _.isString(_getDetails)) {
          // variable assignment.
          _getDetails = JSON.parse(_getDetails)
          _datapipe = await Deeploop(_getDetails)

          // deep loop over container
          // and convert each string method to
          // realmethod.
          for (let {
            parent,
            key,
            value
          } of _datapipe) {
            // if given value contain's function systax
            if (_String(value).contains('function') && _String(value).contains(') {') && !_.isEmpty(parent[key])) {
              console.log('-----ew--', value)
              // assign new anonymus function.
              parent[key] = JSON.parse(value)
            }
          }

          console.log(_getDetails)

          // return details.
          return _getDetails
        } else {
          // return empty data.
          return null
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // report failure.
        throw error
      }
    }
```

#### `.set()` Method

```
async () => {
      // error handling.
      try {
        // local variable.
        let _oldData, _dataContainer, _Cache

        // variable assignment.
        _dataContainer = {}

        // if whatToStore and key is not empty.
        if (!_.isEmpty(_id)) {
          // only update with data if data is passed.
          // else if whatToStore is null than set null
          // to remove all data.
          if (!_.isEmpty(whatToStore) || whatToStore) {
            // check if data already exist.
            // if exist than merge old data
            // with new data.
            _oldData = await getAsync(_id)

            // if old data is not empty.
            if (!_.isEmpty(_oldData)) {
              // parse _oldData to JSON.
              if (_.isString(_oldData) && _oldData.indexOf('{') === 0) {
                // update oldData to container.
                _dataContainer = JSON.parse(_oldData)
              }
            }

            // if whatToStore is not object
            // than store it as is.
            if (!_.isObject(whatToStore)) {
              // store data as is.
              _Cache = await Client.set(_id, _dataContainer, Redis.print)
            } else {
              // update new Data.
              Object.assign(_dataContainer, whatToStore)

              // only store data if is not cyclic
              // else report failure.
              if (isCyclic(_dataContainer)) {
                // local variable.
                throw new Error('Cyclic dependencies found in dataContainer while storing data in cache..')
              }

              // deep loop over container
              // and convert each method to
              // string.
              for (let {
                parent,
                key,
                value
              } of Deeploop(_dataContainer)) {
                // if value of given value is function
                // than convert given function into
                // string.
                if (_.isFunction(value)) parent[key] = _String(value).s
              }

              // loop over value and store each thing one by one.
              // map data to Redis manager.
              _Cache = await Client.set(_id, JSON.stringify(_dataContainer), Redis.print)
            }

            // if redis set doesn't contain any error.
            if (_Cache) {
              // return cached data.
              return getAsync(_id)
            }
          } else {
            // return cached data.
            return getAsync(_id)
          }
        } else {
          // local variable.
          let error = new Error('[failure] Store require id for storing data.')

          // report failure.
          throw error
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // report failure.
        throw error
      }
    }
```

#### Error

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    ReferenceError: _BeforeBootEmit is not defined
    at BeforeBootEmit (eval at _callee3$ (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/_terminal/local/store/index.js:213:29), <anonymous>:3:13)
    at _callee3$ (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/_terminal/local/store/index.js:213:29)
    at tryCatch (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/_terminal/local/store/index.js:26:24)
    at _next (/Users/lefo-meo/WebstormProjects/servers/terminal_Os/currentrequest/_terminal/local/store/index.js:48:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the Cache"? Are you storing JSON data in a cookie / localStorage? You can't store executable code (methods) in a JSON file. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: no, I am saving javascript object to localstorage[redis]. when it comes to executable's I am converting them to string.

Comment: OK, but it's still not possible to convert a JSON string back to an executable function... :)